# Bootstrap Vue - is there any way to time out a message box confirmation modal?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm new to both JS and stackoverflow, so please let me know if I need to provide more detail, or if there is a better approach.

My goal is to have a modal (preferably the msgBoxConfirm modal) close, or "Cancel" programmatically after a set time period when no input is given. I've tried wrapping it in a setTimeout and calling a time out function from within .then, but failed in both attempts.

Here is a scaffold of the code I'd like to add a time out to:

```
timedModalAlert: function () {
  this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm('Session expiration in XX. Press OK to continue.')
  .then(value => {
    if (value == true) {
      // function to refresh token
    } else {
      // function to log user out
    }
  }
  )
}
```

My attempt:

```
timedModalAlert: function () {
  setTimeout (() => {
  this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm('Session expiration in XX. Press OK to continue.')
  .then(value => {
    if (value == true) {
      // function to refresh token
    } else {
      // function to log user out
    }
  }
  )
}, 1000)
```

Comment: why don't u use normal modals and add set time out function  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap-Vue has a method to hide modals, `$bvModal.hide`, which takes a modal id as it's parameter. That means if you give your modal an `ID`, you can then close it again later.

`$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm`, accepts various options as a second parameter. Including an `ID`, so if we give our message box an `ID`. We can then use this `ID` to close it again, after x time has passed using a `setTimeout` and `$bvModal.hide`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    openModal() {
      const modalTimeoutSeconds = 3;
      const modalId = 'confirm-modal'
      let modalSetTimeout = null;      

      this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm(`Session expiration in ${modalTimeoutSeconds} seconds. Press OK to continue.`, {
        id: modalId
      })
      .then(wasOkPressed => {
        if(wasOkPressed) {
          /* Do something */
        } else {
          /* Do something else */
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('The modal closed unexpectedly')
      })
      .finally(() => {
        clearTimeout(modalSetTimeout)
      })
      
      modalSetTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.$bvModal.hide(modalId)
      }, modalTimeoutSeconds * 1000)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.14.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.14.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-btn @click="openModal">
    Open Modal
  </b-btn>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` causes your function to be called after the timeout has expired, so all your code does is delay the message box by a second.

To achieve what you want, you need to start a timer that will cause a log out, then display the message box. If the user doesn't click OK, or doesn't click in time, they will be logged out .Otherwise the timeout is cancelled and their session is refreshed:

```
timedModalAlert: function () {
  let modalId = 'my-modal'
  // Start a timeout, recording the timeout ID for cancelling it
  let timeoutID = setTimeout (() => {
    // function to close the dialog
    this.$bvModal.hide(modalId)
    // OR 
  }, x) // Set the timeout value in ms
  // Display the message box
  this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm('Your session will expire in x. Press OK to continue.', { id: modalId } )
    .then(value => {
      if (value == true) {
        // Stop the timeout
        clearTimeout(timeoutID)
        // function to refresh token
      } else {
        // function to log user out
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! This was actually one of the approaches I've tried, but it doesn't seem to close the modal.

Comment: In the `setTimeout()` function you should be able to do `this.$bvModal.hide()`

Comment: can u edit ur answer so we can check if `this.$bvModal.hide()` works without id

Comment: Have edited to show how to pass `modalId` to the `hide()` function.

Comment: @match did u check in bootstrap vue site how msgBoxOk and msgBoxConfirm modal works ? plz have a look and then come with  right answer

Comment: @match I appreciate the quick responses! Unfortunately, that method didn't seem to work either. Maybe it has to do with the .then waiting for a resolution?

Comment: Have just updated to set modalId correctly - it's not returned by the function - you have to pass one in...